# Extract data of several gene sets from an RNAseq result summary file using R

Tags: r, subset, rna-seq

I am trying to extract data of several gene sets from an RNAseq result summary file:

[image]

Example gene lists:

[image]

I am using Excel to first highlight duplicated genes, sort the summary file, then copy the data I need.  It is time-consuming and Excel always "freeze" when sorting especially for big gene lists.

I was wondering if R can do a better job. Could someone kindly provide the code if R can be a better solution?

Comment: You're question is too broad to answer, but in general you will want to load your data into data.frames, which give you access to a plethora of base R, tidyverse, and/or data.table functions to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution although I still need to process those lists one by one.
It is faster than Excel anyway. :)

```
# read the RNAseq result summary file
result <- read_excel("RNAseq_Result.xlsx")

# read the gene lists file
geneset <- read_excel("Gene set list.xlsx")

# read one specific list from the gene lists file
ListA <- geneset$ListA

#subsetting
ResultListA <- result[(result$Gene_name) %in% ListA, ]

#output file
write.csv(ResultListA, 'ResultListA.csv')
```